Why does = fail to concatenate variables in GNU Make on WSL, but works fine with :=?
Body:
I am experiencing a strange issue with GNU Make on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). When using = for variable assignment, concatenation doesn't work as expected. However, when I switch to :=, everything works fine. The same Makefile works perfectly in a virtual machine running Ubuntu.
Here's a minimal example of my Makefile:
OUTPUT_DIR = 123
BIN = my_program

all:
    echo "$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(BIN)"

Observed Behavior:

On WSL (Ubuntu 20.04):
Running make produces the following output:
/

It seems like $(OUTPUT_DIR) and $(BIN)is empty when concatenated.

On a VM (Ubuntu 20.04):
Running make produces the correct output:
123/my_program




What Works:
If I change the variable assignment from = to := (immediate expansion), it works correctly on both WSL and the virtual machine:
OUTPUT_DIR := 123
BIN := my_program

all:
    echo "$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(BIN)"

With :=, the output is:
123/my_program


My Environment:
1. WSL Environment:

WSL Version: WSL 2
Distro: Ubuntu 20.04
GNU Make Version: 4.3
File System: NTFS (Windows file system)

2. Virtual Machine Environment:

Virtualization Platform: VMware
Distro: Ubuntu 20.04
GNU Make Version: 4.3
File System: ext4

What I've Tried:

Checked File Format:
I verified that the Makefile uses Unix line endings (LF) by running dos2unix Makefile. The issue persists in WSL.

Upgraded WSL and GNU Make:
I ensured that WSL is set to version 2 and that GNU Make is the latest version available (4.3).

Tested Immediate Expansion (:=):
Using := works perfectly, but I want to understand why = fails in WSL specifically.



My Questions:

Why does = fail to concatenate variables in WSL but works in a virtual machine?
Is this related to WSL's underlying file system (NTFS) or the way GNU Make interacts with the WSL environment?
Are there any known issues or workarounds for this behavior?


The output you show can't be the only output of running make.  What was the echo command line that make printed, before it showed the output?  There is no possible reason this should happen, and I've never seen anything like that happen before.  WSL doesn't use NTFS (that is, the root partition inside WSL is not formatted as an NTFS partition, although of course the WSL storage is ultimately on NTFS).  In any event, expansion of make variables is not related to the filesystem.

There's no concatenation in the question, just macro (variable) assignment and expansion.  The semantics of := and = assignments are not equivalent in general, but the difference will not be observable with the makefile presented.  Supposing that you indeed did observe something along the lines you've described, I'm inclined to guess that you cut out the relevant part of your makefile in the process of simplifying it for this question.  We do appreciate your attempt to present a [mre], but you must always verify that your MRE provides a bona fide example of the issue.
